# Missing from the TypeScrypt compilation error after update angular 4.4 to 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I updated a 4.4 angular app to angular 6.

I had several errors but I fixed them, and now when I run `npm run start`, at the end of the compilation (about 92%) I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-lorem-ipsum/lib/ngx-lorem-ipsum.component.ts
Module build failed: Error: /application/node_modules/ngx-lorem-ipsum/lib/ngx-lorem-ipsum.component.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview).
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/application/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:749:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/application/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:41:31)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I searched how to solve it and I read that writing:

```
"paths": {
  "@ngx-lorem-ipsum/": [ "./node_modules/ngx-lorem-ipsum/lib/" ],
},
```

at the end of the tsconfig.json It should be fixed. But the compilation keeps failing with the same error.

Now tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@ngx-lorem-ipsum/": [ "./node_modules/ngx-lorem-ipsum/lib/" ],
    },
  }
}
```

How to solve the missing from the TypeScrypt compilation error?

- Angular CLI: 6.1.5
- Node: 8.9.4
- OS: darwin x64
- Angular: 6.1.4
- ngx-lorem-ipsum: ^0.1.1

Comment: This is a known breaking change in Angular 5. Have you tried adding the library directories to the `include` key in your tsconfig.json?

Comment: I have no include key in the tsconfig.json, maybe it goes on the /src/tsconfig.app.json ?
Use include key makes another error in comilation: tsconfig.json(23,5): error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'include'.

Comment: Oh Thank you, I solved it now. I was placing the include inside the compileroptions, and it goes on the first level. Now it seems that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, thanks to the comment of Mikhail Burshteyn, I solved it. I had to add the library directories to the tsconfig.json with a `include` tag.

Now the tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "node_modules/ngx-lorem-ipsum/**/*.ts"
    ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@ngx-lorem-ipsum/": [ "./node_modules/ngx-lorem-ipsum/lib/" ],
    },
  }
}
```